# KeyError: 0 - loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

I am trying to multiply the value of the 'Data' column by the value of the cell in the same column above it, i.e. Data * Data(t-1), so have constructed a loop as below, however I am getting an error that I am not sure how to fix - is anyone please able to see where I went wrong?

```
df.head()

Date    Data
04/01/2016  -0.466844
05/01/2016  -0.477460
06/01/2016  -0.477849
13/01/2016  -0.499518
14/01/2016  -0.491221

df['Data_sq'] = df['Data']**2

df['Data_x_Data_t1'] = ""

#data*data(t-1) column
i = 1
for i in range(1, len(df)):
   df.loc[i, 'Data_x_Data_t1'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Data'] * df.loc[i, 'Data']
```

The KeyError: 0 that I am receiving:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5d8034885c09> in <module>
      6 i = 1
      7 for i in range(1, len(df)):
----> 8     df.loc[i, 'Data_x_Data_t1'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Data'] * df.loc[i, 'Data']
      9 
     10 #df.head()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1492             except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1493                 pass
-> 1494             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1495         else:
   1496             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    866     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
    867         try:
--> 868             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
    869         except IndexingError:
    870             pass

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
    986         for i, key in enumerate(tup):
    987             if is_label_like(key) or isinstance(key, tuple):
--> 988                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    989 
    990                 # we have yielded a scalar ?

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1911         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1912         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1913         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1914 
   1915 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
    139             raise IndexingError('no slices here, handle elsewhere')
    140 
--> 141         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
    142 
    143     def _get_loc(self, key, axis=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3583                                                       drop_level=drop_level)
   3584         else:
-> 3585             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   3586 
   3587             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: To just fix your code use ```iloc``` instead of ```loc```

Comment: Thanks for the help - when I change to iloc instead of loc, I receive the following error in place: ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types @GrzegorzSkibinski

Comment: Ah, right you would put column Index, instead of its name. Check my answer instead though- it's not really recommended to iterate over ```pandas``` anyways, better do vectorized transformation instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instead of the `for` loop:

```py
df['Data_x_Data_t1'] = df['Data'].shift(1).mul(df['Data'])
```

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html

Comment: That works great as a replacement for what I attempted, thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries, please consider upvoting, and mark it as an answer to close off your question.